# Don't display stock counter for bundle products

Tags: magento, bundle, product

My development website has a traffic light graphic system to illustrate stock levels for each item.
In amongst those simple products, I have a few bundle products (more to come in future).
On the product listings (and details) pages, the stock graphic is always showing red, or out of stock - even when every product contained in the bundle is IN stock.

I figure the only way around this is to hide the stock graphic for all bundle products.

Does anyone know how to do this?
How do I perform a test in code to display (or not) the stock graphic based on the products type_id being bundle?

My worry is that this isn't a great idea due to the added overhead of testing each product before displaying the page??

Any other suggestions are more than welcome!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is far simpler than previously thought.
The following code will check if a product is of type "Bundle" and then conditionally show the stock counter.

```
<?php if($_product->getTypeId() != "bundle"): ?>
[Stock counter display code here]
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope that helps someone else looking for this!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the default theme I see the bundle has it's own template for showing stock status which checks `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type::isSalable()`, this already does the costly operation of loading all it's component products and checking them individually. Also the price works in a similar way, loading the components. It is costly because this is a big EAV operation. Some of the slowest stores I've worked on have notably had a lot of bundle/configurable products.

So the work is already done by the database and looping through the loaded products one more time to check the stock again will probably not be a big deal. Besides you can limit the impact by using something like [CatalogCache](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/2138/catalogcache/).

Unfortunately I don't see a stock quantity event so you may have to extend `Mage_Bundle_Model_Product_Type` with your own `getStockQty()` method to do the appropriate lookups and calculation.

If you have already changed the stock display then it would have been in the `template/bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml` file. Remove the 'traffic lights' from there if you want the simplest way to hide bundle's stock level. This does not affect other product types.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and apologies for leaving this so long!
Let's ignore the stock level display thing temporarily - lets say I just want to hide a portion of the product data on the listing page template and I need to test each one in the loop before it is displayed.
The test to be performed needs to determine if the product is a bundle product or not. I believe there is a type_id for each prodyct type, but here is the question:

How do I check each product's typeid. Is there such a thing as getTypeID() function?

Comment: Nearly all objects in Magento use magic getters so you can use `getTypeId()` to find the value of `type_id` even if there is no explicit function. The equivalent is true for `setTypeId()` and other setters. The name conversion is [camelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).